# Repeat bottom elements for top-overscroll in Android ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a simple `ListView` in my Android application that gets its data from a custom `ArrayAdapter`.

When you scroll up to the top and try to scroll further (same for bottom), there's the overscroll that is shown to the user with the bounce effect.

However, I would like to change my `ListView` in so far that, if you scroll over the top, the `ListView` will display the elements from the bottom (in reverse order) again. Is this possible without re-implementing the complete `ListView` or `ArrayAdapter`?

What modifications are necessary?

Comment: "in reverse order" -- what does this mean? Suppose the list has three elements: A, B, C. The user attempts to scroll up past A. What is the row that appears immediately above A? Is it C? Is it another copy of A?

Comment: I am pretty sure he wants an infinite scroll that just repeats items over and over

Comment: @GregEnnis: That would have been my interpretation without the "in reverse order" bit, which is why I asked for clarification.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Sorry for being imprecise. Yes, the infinite scroll is basically what I want. But I don't really want it to be infinite, but just repeat the list once. After that, it should stop. And the reverse order means: If your list consists of [A,B,C], you will first see C and then B (and then A again) when scrolling over the top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is pretty easy to do this. You don't have to re-invent listview. You can derive from `BaseAdapter` and just return a very high number for `getCount`, let's say 1 million. Have the initial scroll position start at item half million. Then in `getView` just mod the request position by the actual count of items you have.